# python nested list on second item

Tags: python, list, sorting

i have a nested list that needs to be sorted alphabetic on index 1

example:

```
some_list = [
    [85, u'Bounty Prizes'],
    [34, u'Agent Mission Time Bonus Reward'],
    [46, u'Brokers Fee'],
    [83, u'Contract Reward Deposited'],
    [17, u'Bounty Prize'],
    [1, u'Player Trading'],
    [15, u'Repair Bill'],
    [10, u'Player Donation']
]

sorted(some_list)
```

but this sorts on index 0. how can I sort on the second item?

Comment: Thanks, I guess i missed that one while googling

Comment: Thanks a lot! I reached 10k coz of your edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `key` argument to the sorted function

```
sorted(some_list, key = lambda x:x[1])
```

Refer: The [documentation for sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element

Another way

```
>>> import operator
>>> sorted(some_list, key = operator.itemgetter(1))
```